# command terminated with exit code 1 when executing aws s3 cp in Jenkins Declarative Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-s3, kubernetes, kubectl

I'm trying to upload my files to AWS S3 Bucket from my Kubernetes Pod thru Jenkins and got `command terminated with exit code 1`. Succeeding commands are terminated.

I've tried to manually run my command on the pod, and it works perfectly fine.

Here's my code on jenkins declarative pipeline:

`sh (script: "kubectl exec -i ${MONGODB_POD_NAME} -n ${ENVIRONMENT} -- bash -c 'aws s3 sync /dump/${AUTOMATION_DUMP_DIRECTORY} s3://${S3_BUCKET}/${ENVIRONMENT}/${AUTOMATION_DUMP_DIRECTORY} --debug'")`

Here's the log:

`2019-04-29 09:55:23,373 - Thread-1 - awscli.customizations.s3.results - DEBUG - Shutdown request received in result processing thread,shutting down result thread.command terminated with exit code 1`

Comment: does it work in Freestyle Job?

Comment: Is that all the error log you see? do you see any traceback? When you run in the pod you also use `--debug`?

Comment: I was having this problem on aws-cli-2.4.27.
Upgraded to 2.9.19 and the problem vanished.
Not sure in which version the bug was fixed.